# Ruby on rails change status in runtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I made an application in rails 3.0.9...in that application I have one form which is having an address field. Now first time if user enters the address field(say "ABC") status should be 1, but when another time user is entering new address(say "XYZ") and then submits ts status should be 1 and the ABC status should be 0.
If now user enters another address say "PQR" and submits then its status should be 1 and XYZ status should be 0 and so on. 
For example, there are 10 address in database and first 9 address are having status 0 and 10th is having 1. If user enters another address then 11th should be 1 and 10th should be 0.
I don't know how to change value in runtime in table...

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Do you want to keep track of active / inactive address versions? If so, why not simply use a "created_at" field for the address containing a timestamp? Based on the timestamp, you can select the most current and therefore "active" address.

Comment: Actually its a very huge project, and what i am asking is just a part of a module... what I want, there is an address if any new address is added in database its status must be 1 and the remaining address status must be 0....I mean whenever new user enters address and submits it its status will be 1 and remaining will be 0.... Whether I have to use some if condition that if current user then status 1 , something like that?????????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with [ActiveRecord's update_all method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all). Simply define a callback in your model:

```
before_create :update_address_statuses

def update_address_statuses
  MyModel.update_all("status = 0")
  self.status = 1
end
```

However, as blackbird07 pointed out, you probably need to rethink how you're using addresses in your application, and simply fetch the most recently updated address, rather than updating every field of a table.